# Verify the given error 0f 0.1813 is accurate by approximating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ by the first 5 terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Verify that the error in approximating the first 5 terms of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is approximately 0.1813.
The formula I have to find the error is if $S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ converges for $|x|<1$, and if $|a_{n+1}|<|a_{n}|$ then for $n>N$ $$\left | S-\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{n}x^{n}\right | <|a_{N+1}x^{N+1}\div(1-|x|)$$
I'm currently confused because if I rewrite $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot x^n$, with x being equal to 1, then my $|x|$ is 1 and then when I try to find the error I'm dividing by zero.

Comment: Is really the summation starting at $n=0$ ?

Comment: yea that's what it says in my textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is $\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ and this we have to estimate. We'll use the Kummer's method for  [summation of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) : approximate the terms of the series with the terms of some telescoping series. In our case we use the equalities
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{n^2} &=& \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})} - \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{n^2(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})} = \\
&=& \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})}  - \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})}+ \frac{\frac{9}{16}}{n^2(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})}
\end{eqnarray}

We conclude:
\begin{eqnarray} 
\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})}  - \sum_{n=6}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})} + \\
+ \sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{9}{16}}{n^2(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})}
\end{eqnarray}

The first two series can be calculated exactly, for the third we'll give an upper bound. Let's do the second one. We have the decomposition into partial fraction:
\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})}
= \frac{1}{12}\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2n-3} - \frac{1}{2n+3}\right) - \frac{1}{4}\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})} = \frac{1}{12} \cdot\left( \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} +\frac{1}{13} \right) - \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{11}= \frac{2}{3861}
\end{eqnarray}
Similarly, we have $\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})}= \frac{2}{11}$.

Therefore, from the first two series we get $\frac{2}{11}- \frac{2}{3861} = \frac{700}{3861}= 0.(181300)$ ( periodic fraction). The third series has  the sum less than
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{9}{16}}{(n-\frac{5}{2})(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})(n+ \frac{5}{2})}= \frac{2}{75075} = 0.00(00264)
\end{eqnarray}
We therefore get the estimate of the error 
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}= 0.1813...
\end{eqnarray}